# What is the most reliable book of Seerah (biography) of Muhammad?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, seerah

There are many Seerah biography books written of the life and times of Prophet Muhammad (s), and history of early Islam. Such as al-Tabari, ibn Ishaq ibn Kathir, ibn Sa'd, al Waqidi etc. But my question is which is the most reliable and authentic?

Comment: I'm afraid this will be somewhat opinion-based.